# Python - simplest way to write a XML file in a specific folder

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I wrote a Python script to generate XML log files but every time I run it, it is saved/written in the same folder/path as the script itself.

Here is a simplified version of it:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("LOG")

Child_1 = ET.SubElement(root, "CHILD1")
Child_1.text = "I am child 1"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("log_file.xml")
```

However, I want to save/write it in a specific folder. What is the simplest way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dir like this:

```
import os
path = os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", os.getlogin(), "Desktop","log_file.xml")
```

Then you can just do this:

```
tree.write(path)
```